# Where to find documentation about DAG optimizations?

Tags: apache-flink

Is there any documentation about what (and how are performed) are the optimizations that are performed when transforming the Application DAG into the physical DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "official" page of [Flink Optimizer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Optimizer+Internals) but it is awfully incomplete. 
I've also found other information directly in the source-code on the [official github page](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-optimizer/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/optimizer/Optimizer.java) but it is very difficult to read and understand.

Other information can be found [here (section 6)](http://stratosphere.eu/assets/papers/2014-VLDBJ_Stratosphere_Overview.pdf) (Stratosphere was the previous name of Flink before it was incubated by Apache) and [here (section 5.1)](https://www.user.tu-berlin.de/asteriosk/assets/publications/flink-deb.pdf) for a more theoretical documentation.

I hope it will be documented better in the future :-)